# Nano Power Soft Latch

Tags: microcontroller, low-power, latch, rtc

I need to latch an INT output with a time width of 7 ms. This signal is generated by an RTC clock and I need to enable an LDO with it. The LDO powers an MCU, which at the end of its program should be switched off.
The main issue is to design a nA range circuit.

I've seen some On/Off Controller ICs for Maxim, but they have debouncing and they will not work with this time width.

EDIT:
Here is the circuit I've designed.
I am using a TPS73733 LDO and a RV3028-C7 RTC. The MCU is an ATmega328P
[image: Circuit]

Comment: How about a series diode, a capacitor to ground, and then as soon as the MCU wakes up take over driving the enable from that.  When it want to turn itself off it grounds the enable.

Comment: hm, why do you need a nanoampere thing if you're using a separate RTC? where does that RTC get its current from? Wouldn't a microcontroller with a built-in RTC with wakeup abilities solve this all in one wash?

Comment: Virtually any CMOS logic chip draws nA *typically* with inputs in the proper range etc.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have some specific constraints on the BOM. The RTC I'm using has 11 nA consumption

Comment: How about you `edit` the question and include the whole circuit - RTC, regulator, MCU with part numbers, and leave the part you are asking about as a conceptual black box.  If you could leave the MCU powered and merely in sleep mode that might be better, I'm guessing you don't want to do that because of the regulator quiescent current... what is the power source?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I've edited the post